# Object Array in a Object 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a Object 2-dimensional array, let's say Result[][] where I have 2 columns and multiple rows (dynamic depends on database). Now as a column I have 1 array for each row lets say result.

```
Example:      column column  column
              1      hello   1,2,3,4
              2      hi      4,3,2,1
              3      bye     5,2,1,3,6
```

So I need a object which acts as a column in a 2 dimensional Array object.
I am not getting the way out of the problem.

My code is:

```
public Object[][] getGroupDetails(String org_id, Object[][] result) {
    Object[][] result2 = null;
    Object[][] list = null;
    System.out.println(result.length);
    Integer len = result.length;
    //String groups_id="";
    try {
        Integer i = 0;
        while (i < len) {

            String getBelongingGroupsList = "SELECT DISTINCT groups.GROUPS_NAME, groups.GROUPS_ID FROM groups LEFT JOIN member "
                    + "ON member.GROUPS_ID=groups.GROUPS_ID WHERE groups.org_id=" + org_id + " AND member.member_number =" + result[i][1];
            System.out.println("getBelongingGroupsList  " + getBelongingGroupsList);
            ResultSet rscheck = (ResultSet) DataService.getResultSet(getBelongingGroupsList);
            list = (Object[][]) DataService.getDataFromResultSet(rscheck);
            System.out.println("list made");
            System.out.println(list.length);//not executing bhai kya hua teko
            for (int j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
                System.out.println("copying list to object ");
                result[i][j] = list[j][0];
            }
            //System.out.println(result2[i].length);
            //groups_id = rscheck.getString("groups_id");
            i++;

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Did you figure out the solution? Or is it still pending?

Comment: i have tried using a 3D array but it is not helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following. It stores the result index as well. Let me know if this helps.

```
    String[] col;
    List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();    

    col = new String[3];        
    col[0] = "1";
    col[1] = "hello";
    col[2] = "1,2,3,4";
    list.add(col);

    col = new String[3];
    col[0] = "2"; 
    col[1] = "hi";
    col[2] = "4,3,2,1";
    list.add(col);


    for(String[] objs : list){
        for(String str : objs){
            System.out.print(str + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

---

And the output will be :

```
1   hello   1,2,3,4 
2   hi      4,3,2,1
```

Comment: Thanks for the best possible answer ... well i did something to get my purpose solve but i definitely change it to make it more simpler like u suggested !!